# Error from graphviz in python (windows 7)

Tags: python, windows, graphviz

I have a problem with Graphviz in python.

#### Issue

I tried to produce some plot from python using the python module `graphviz`, but I got the error message:

> RuntimeError: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg', '-O', 'Digraph.gv'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' path

#### Environment

I installed Graphviz on Windows. However, every time I install it (install process is fine), it always was installed on root directory of the secondary drive (not C drive).
I am using my work computer but I have admin rights.

#### What I tried

I add the dot.exe directory to system path, but nothing happened.

How are these problems related?

Comment: What is the python command you are using which gives that error? Can you execute dot from the command line by just typing dot?

Comment: @barny, if I install graphviz from pip, ie `pip install graphviz` does it not have all the graphviz internals on hand for rendering a graph file? I have to install graphviz in addition to the python module?

Comment: Yikes, looks like it, [To render the generated DOT source code, you also need to install Graphviz (download page). ](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz)